# Spring batch in Websphere 8.x

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing, spring-batch, websphere-8, java-batch

JSR 352 is defined in Java EE7. But in WebSphere 8.x, only Java EE6 is supported. As far as I know, Spring batch 3.x is compatible with JSR 352. My question is, can Spring batch run in WebSphere 8.x (and other app server which supports JEE6 only)? Especially does Parallel Processing still work as concurrency executor is also part of Java EE7?

Comment: You could also consider native WebSphere [batch support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/container_computegrid_developing.html?lang=en) or WebSphere Liberty Beta, which [supports JSR 352](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_container_batch.html?lang=en)

Comment: We want to support both Websphere and JBoss. Does JBoss has native batch implementation which supports JSR 352? We won't write application server specific codes or annotation, just use standard java package.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch runs in WebSphere 8.  Spring Batch has taken the position that it will remain compliant with all version of app servers/java versions that the current Spring Framework supports.  Currently, Spring 4.1.x supports back to Java 6 and runs on WebSphere 8, so Spring Batch does as well.